# R get the logical working directory

Tags: r, path

I have some symlinks on the server I'm deploying my `R` app and I need to know the logical (symbolic) path to working directory:

```
16:18 $ ls -alh
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  staff   136B Mar 16 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  40 user  staff   1.3K Mar 16 16:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 user  staff    68B Mar 16 16:17 test1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff     5B Mar 16 16:18 test3 -> test1

16:25 $ pwd -P
/physical/path/to/test/test1
16:25 $ pwd -L
/logical/path/to/test/test3
```

In R when you use `getwd` function it returns the *physical* path. In that case this would be `/physical/path/to/test/test1`. I'd like to get the *symbolic* (logical) path to that directory: `/logical/path/to/test/test3`.

Is it possible to get the logical path using an R function?

I know that there is an option of using `system("pwd -L")` but I was wondering if there is an R function for that.

**EDIT:**
I've checked and `system("pwd -L")` doesn't work either.